# Rails: How to retrieve URL of Paperclip uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am having trouble retrieving the URL of images uploaded via **Paperclip**.

I set the URL using the following code in my **model**:

```
has_attached_file :banner,
                  :path => "/www/banners/:foo-:id.:extension",
                  :url => "http://example.com/:foo-:id.:extension"
```

In my **views**, I can retrieve the URL just fine by running **@gallery.banner.url**

The problem arises when I try to retrieve the same **banner.url** in a **rake** task. There is no column for **url** in the database table, so how does my controller and view know what it is?

My guess is this has something to do with the controller using **Gallery.find** to retrieve the object, whereas my rake task uses **Gallery.where** to find the objects.

I am using Rails 3 and loading the Rails environment in the rake task.

Comment: If its loading the Rails environment, then why wouldn't @gallery.banner.url work?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller and view know where it is because you've specified the URL in your 'has_attached_file' parameters. I.e. ':path'